# How to use Firebase RealtimeDatabase like a common Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The Firebase RealtimeDatabase works with Listeners, when a event happen so the function is triggered, but I wants a option to update the data when a Button is clicked, for example. I learned about this and found the method *DatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent*, but keeping be a listener. So, exists a way to solve my problem? I'm working with Android.

Comment: ... If you want to make it non real-time I guess you could just go offline and then back online. Why use any lib as intended anyway? Forget efficiency and effort. Forget the client RIIIGHT?!

Comment: What is your question? Please state it clearly in the post.

Answer (score 0):

when a Button is clicked you can use method DatabaseReference.addValueEventListener() to get data from firebase.
And whenever you need cancel this listener: call DatabaseReference.removeEventListener(valueEvenListener);
Sorry my bad English :( :( :(

Answer (score 0):

The main goal of Firebase databases is to work as Real-time databases and not to work as offline databases. Firebase applications work even if your app temporarily loses its network connection. Cached data is available while offline and Firebase resends any writes when network connectivity is restored.

When you enable disk persistence, your app writes the data locally to the device so your app can maintain state while offline. You can enable disk persistence like this:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

If you want to be compltely offilne you can use [goOffline() method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase#goOffline())

> This method shuts down our connection to the Firebase Database backend until goOnline() is called.

However, i don't recomand you using Firebase as an offline-only database. It is really designed as an online database that came work for short to intermediate periods of being disconnected. While offline it will keep queue of write operations. As this queue grows, local operations and app startup will slow down. Nothing major, but over time these may add up.

Hope it helps.